# послать JSON запрос CURL

Tags: linux, json, bash, http, curl

**Нужно отправить json-запрос при помощи утилиты Curl  на сервис по распознаванию эмоций**

Сервис https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize , который распознает эмоции на лице человека на фото.

В описании указаны примеры для разных ЯП и для Curl:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

в {body} должен быть url изображения.

в ключ - уникальный ключ для доступа, который можно получить при регистрации.
У меня такой ключ есть, предоставлю 1 ключ, потом сгенерирую заново, когда вопрос закроется.

9cd1728ed38c49278236aae4b56d9ade

Ключ рабочий, можете использовать.

Пример моего запроса:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 0022db3b0ff34391b6e60dea801086bc" --data-ascii "{"url": "http://images.webpark.ru/uploads54/110818/Portraits_04.jpg"}"
```

Мой ответ:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.68.24.134...
* Connected to api.projectoxford.ai (40.68.24.134) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=*.projectoxford.ai
*        start date: 2015-04-14 04:15:32 GMT
*        expire date: 2017-04-13 04:15:32 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api.projectoxford.ai matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /emotion/v1.0/recognize HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: api.projectoxford.ai
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 0022db3b0ff34391b6e60dea801086bc
> Content-Length: 65
>
* upload completely sent off: 65 out of 65 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 60
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< apim-request-id: b7f40e3a-6205-4a71-9cd8-9f0e9f9f5d0e
< Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2016 16:31:47 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host api.projectoxford.ai left intact
{"error":{"code":"BadBody","message":"JSON parsing error."}}
```

Как видите, ничего не выходит, т.к. ответ должен быть в формате:

```
    [
  {
    "faceRectangle": {
      "left": 68,
      "top": 97,
      "width": 64,
      "height": 97
    },
    "scores": {
      "anger": 0.00300731952,
      "contempt": 5.14648448E-08,
      "disgust": 9.180124E-06,
      "fear": 0.0001912825,
      "happiness": 0.9875571,
      "neutral": 0.0009861537,
      "sadness": 1.889955E-05,
      "surprise": 0.008229999
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двойные кавычки, которые используются до и после тела запроса в параметре --data-ascii замените на одинарные.

```
--data-ascii '{"url": "http://images.webpark.ru/uploads54/110818/Portraits_04.jpg"}'
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало. 
А вы не могли бы объяснить почему именно одинарные кавычки? 
И почему этого нет в примере?

Comment: Все просто, по сути вы могли бы заменить внутренние кавычки на одинарные, а внешние на двойные и тогда бы тоже работало. Проблема в том, что если у вас везде используется один тип кавычек, при отсылке они отрезаются и на сервер приходит значение: "{url: http://images.webpark.ru/uploads54/110818/Portraits_04.jpg}", в котором отсуствуют кавычки по стандарту json.

Comment: Верно ли я понял, что отрезаются вообще все кавычки? Тогда неясно почему нельзя ставить и там и там одинарные ковычки или и там и там двойные, как это и было.

Comment: У вас первые кавычки (одинарные), чтобы показать командной строке, какие данные брать. Вторые и далее (двойные) используются в теле запроса для JSON. Bash не понимает просто, до какого момента брать данные. Первая кавычка, символ } и опять эта кавычка, значит по сути данные вот они. Но в Bash как-то происходит по умному и он отсекает внутренние кавычки совсем. Вы бы могли использовать и двойные кавычки везде, если бы использовали экранирование в теле запроса:

--data-ascii "{\"url\": \"http://images.webpark.ru/uploads54/110818/Portraits_04.jpg\"}"

Comment: Просто при использовании разных кавычек отпадает необходимость экранирования их в теле.

Comment: Благодарю! Врядли бы я догадался об экранировании или о том, как bash обрабатывает кавычки.
Теперь у меня ясное понимание в голове того, что  одни кавычки мы используем для bash, а другие для запроса, и что идущие подряд двойные кавычки могут быть интерпретированы, не как вложенные кавычки, а иначе - как открытие и закрытие.